# Project with SpriteView runs but animation does not show in simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

Have started exploring SpriteView and I have gotten to the point which the editor recognizes the SpriteView object and runs, but the simulator screen stays black.

The scene runs and everything in the scene editor too.

Am I missing something? Is there some sort of initialization step that I'm missing?

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
        scene.backgroundColor = .white
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
       SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            .ignoresSafeArea()

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a single view WatchOS app at the moment.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Xcode 13RC, Series 7 - 41 mm simulator. I suspect your issue is with your scene kit set up.